# How to protect some code from SIG terminating with threads/mutex?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mutex

I make some important calculations in endless loop and don't want this calculation interrupts with SIGINT signal (e.g. ctrl-c). So I place loop in thread with protecting important calculation with mutex:

```
mutex = Mutex.new

trap('INT') do
  Thread.new do
    puts 'Terminating..'
    exit(0)
  end.join
end

Thread.new do
  loop do
    mutex.synchronize do
      puts 'Some important computation is started.'
      sleep(5)
      puts 'Some important computation is done.'
    end

    sleep(30)
  end
end.join
```

I add another thread inside trap block, so I expect this thread will be executed only when mutex will be unlocked.

But in fact, this second thread starts immediately after receiving SIGINT signal:

```
Some important computation is started.
^CTerminating..
```

What am I missed/doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must synchronize the trap thread with the computation:

```
  trap('INT') do
    Thread.new do
       mutex.synchronize do
          puts 'Terminating..'
          exit(0)
       end  
    end.join
  end
```

But perhaps it is easier if you set a boolean var in your trap function, and you use it to break the loop.

```
mustexit = false

trap('INT') do
  mustexit= true
end

Thread.new do
loop do    
  puts 'Some important computation is started.'
  sleep(5)
  puts 'Some important computation is done.'
  if mustexit then
     break
  end
end

sleep(30)
end.join
```

Comment: Thank you. The second variant is not appropriate, because second `sleep` should be inside loop too, and I don't want to wait for it when receive signal.